# Accessing IMarkupExtension in other projects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm doing self-learning on XamarinForms, according to Charles Petzold's book. I need explanation on what he did here:

1. Created a class library project. Referenced that project in main project.
2. In the class library project, there's 2 class. One is inheriting from IMarkupExtension, another is simply an empty class with empty Init() function.
3. It is mentioned that in order to access the markup extension class from XAML, "the library needs to be accessed from actual code". So he did something like this in App.cs:

   ```
   public App()
   {
       Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit.Toolkit.Init();       //How is calling an empty function that does ntg helps here?
       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainLoginPage());
   }
   ```
4. Only then can the markup extension class be called in the XAML, like this (I can't put XAML code here?):

[image: XamlExtension]

Someone please help explain to me why is that Init() needed, when it's just an empty function? How is that helping me access the markup extension class in another project, different namespace? What kinds of sorcery is this?

Comment: I am not sure, but it's a trick to keep library from linking out during the compilation

Comment: Any official documentation about this? How does this work behind? Is this something specific to .NET in general or only for Xamarin?

Comment: are you asking about the linking? or adding controls to xaml page?

Comment: The linking, of course

Comment: here you go https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/